# Having "permission denied" issues for PhantomJS on OSX Catalina

Tags: macos, phantomjs, permission-denied, macos-catalina

I seem to be having issues with running my Python code with PhantomJS after upgrading to OSX Catalina. I have tried several things:

- Going to ../bin/macosx/phantomjs and making the whole folder and items "Read & Write" for every type of user.
- Placing a copy of phantomjs in user/local/bin
- Adding it to path via this code "export PATH=${PATH:+$PATH:}/Library/.../site-packages/phantomjs/bin"
- Instead of using "from phantomjs_bin import executable_path" I specifically directed executable_path to phantomjs
- Banging my head against the screen vigorously

Nothing seems to work, and I'm wondering if any of you seem to have this problem or found a workaround. I was considering rolling back to the patched version of PhantomJS Binary 2.0, but I wanted to see if anyone has gotten it to work with 2.1 before I did that because I'm not the only working on this code and I'm the only one having this problem.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=executable_path)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 88, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: **Message: 'phantomjs' executable may have wrong permissions**.
```

Comment: Error message might be useful in determining the improperly permissed target.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I added the error code below!